# Populate jqgrid dropdown list with JSON data using editoptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

I am new to web development, I have run into this problem and have researched and tried many other methods to no avail. I need to populate a drop down list in a jqgrid only with values that are in my database. The url that I am using to do this gives me the correct response in JSON as follows (note that I only sent through selected fields):

```
{
  "serviceBranchResult": [
    {
      "branch_services": [],
      "queues": [],
      "service_description": null,
      "service_id": 2,
      "service_name": "Forex",
      "service_status": null
    },
    {
      "branch_services": [],
      "queues": [],
      "service_description": null,
      "service_id": 3,
      "service_name": "Tellers",
      "service_status": null
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to do a dropdownlist from the method below without reading the json from the url it works 100% however it isnt dynamic, I use the method getAllSelectOptions() and where I am using it in the grid looks like this:

```
function getAllSelectOptions() {

var services = {
'1':'Forex', '2':'Tellers', '3':'Consultants'};

return services;

}
```

My code for the grid:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/service.svc/employees/3"
datatype: "json",
type: "GET",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
height: '250',                           
colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Username', 'Email', 'Branch ID', 'User Type', 'Status', 'Speciality'],
                            colModel: [
                                    { name: 'employee_id', index: 'employee_id'},
                                    { name: 'employee_name', index: 'employee_name', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'employee_surname', index: 'employee_surname', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'employee_username', index: 'employee_username', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'employee_email', index: 'employee_email', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'branch_id', index: 'branch_id', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'user_type', index: 'user_type', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'employee_state', index: 'employee_state', editable: true },
                                    { name: 'employee_speciality', index: 'employee_speciality', editable: true,
                                        sortable: true,
                                        align: 'center',
                                        editable: true,
                                        cellEdit: true,
                                        edittype: 'select',
                                        formatter: 'select',
                                        editoptions: { value: getAllSelectOptions() }

                                    }],

                                rowNum: 20,
                                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                                pager: '#pager_jqgrid',
```

And this works perfectly.
However I use this following method to potentially replace the getAllSelectOptions() method and it does return the information when I use alert boxes, but does not work.

```
function availAtBranch() {


                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/service.svc/branch/3",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $.each(data.serviceBranchResult, function (i, obj) {
                                        //alert(obj.service_id + ":" + obj.service_name);
                                        var div_data = obj.service_name + ":" + obj.service_name;
                                        //alert(div_data);

                                    });

                                    return div_data;

                                }

                            });
```

I think it has something to do with how in parsing the JSON to the editoptions method, or sending an object through. How do I get my JSON to be in the format as described in the getAllSelectOptions() method, or how do I display my data in the dropdownlist. Thank you in advance